# Jest chained mockReturnValueOnce for createQueryBuilder mock doesn't work

Tags: testing, jestjs, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to test my `nestjs app` with unit tests using `Jest` and stuck on returning mocked value. Here is what I do.
My `createQueryBuilderMock` looks like:

```
const createQueryBuilderMock = jest.fn(() => ({
  leftJoin: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  take: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  skip: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  orderBy: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  addSelect: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  andWhere: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  getManyAndCount: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce([myDataAllMock, 2]).mockReturnValueOnce([myDataAllMock[1], 1])
}));
```

So I want to test two cases and chaining returned value. Here is my testing module part where I use this value:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
          providers: [
            MyService,
            {
              provide: MY_REPOSITORY,
              useValue: {
                createQueryBuilder: createQueryBuilderMock,
              }
            }
          ],
        }).compile();
    })
```

And the test cases described:

```
describe('getAll', () => {
    it('should return all data', async () => {
      expect(await service.getAll({ perPage: 250, page: 1 } as GetMyDataDTO)).toEqual({
        meta: {...metaMock, totalItems: 2},
        myData: mappedMyDataMock,
      });
    });

    it('should return filtered by orderNumber data', async () => {
      expect(await service.getAll({ perPage: 250, page: 1, orderNumber: '12553624' } as GetMyDataDTO)).toEqual({
        meta: metaMock,
        myData: [mappedMyDataMock[1]],
      });
    });
  });
```

The problem is that `.mockReturnValueOnce([myDataAllMock[1], 1])` doesn't work and second test fails because I get first value `.mockReturnValueOnce([myDataAllMock, 2])`. Why doesn't that work as expected? Or am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Do you maybe create the mock in the beforeEach hook?

Comment: @dyedwiper yes.

Comment: Then the mock is reinitialized before each test and it doesn't know about the calls in prior tests. Creating it in the beforeAll hook should fix it.

Comment: In most cases it is also a better practice to create the TestingModule in the beforeAll hook because you normally don't need a newly created module for each test. Your tests will run faster if you create it just once.

Comment: @dyedwiper I tried - didn't help.

Comment: Hm.. Can you paste your whole test setup?

Comment: @dyedwiper which part do you need? Site blocks my question if I paste too much code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255143/discussion-between-dyedwiper-and-jun).